# Как из другого процесса в Си вывести время?

Tags: linux, c, unix

Доброго настоящего всем. Разбираюсь тут с процессами в языке С, но кое-что не получается. Стоит такая задача:

*Написать программу, создающую два дочерних процесса с использованием двух вызовов fork() . Родительский и два дочерних процесса должны выводить на экран свой pid и pid родительского процесса и текущее время в формате: часы: минуты : секунды : миллисекунды . Используя вызов system() , выполнить команду
ps -x в родительском процессе.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    pid_t pid1, pid2;
    if ((pid1 = fork()) == 0)
    {
        pid1 = getpid();
        printf("\nДочерний процесс 1: pid = %d\n", pid1);
        //вывод времени
    }
    if ((pid2 = fork()) == 0)
    {
        pid2 = getpid();        
        printf("\nДочерний процесс 2: pid = %d\n", pid2);
        ////вывод времени
    }
    puts("");
    system("ps -x");
    printf("Родительский процесс: pid = %d\n", getppid());
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я делаю?И вот как ещё вывести время?(в Ubuntu)
**Заранее большое спасибо за ответы!**

Comment: Вы никак не проверяете перед форком и перед `system`, что это выполняется в родительском процессе. Соответственно, в выводе будет два «дочерних процесса 2» и три «родительских» процесса

Comment: Вы забыли вызвать `exit()` в конце кода каждого из процессов-потомков. Это приведет к тому, что код после соответствующего `if` будет выполняться не только в родительском процессе, но и в каждом из потомков.

Comment: задача вывести время в заданном формате никак не связана с ошибками с fork в вашем коде. Лучше в отдельных вопросах обсуждать. Так и ответы более информативные будут и полезны большему кругу людей.